# Managed Identity for Azure AppService with Graph API

Tags: azure-managed-identity

I need to implement "**Managed Identity**"

Source: **App Service**
Destination: **Graph API**
Type: **Managed Identity => User Identity**

What are the steps to implement MI for AppService using User Identity, to call Graph API. Need to call Graph API to get user's Security Groups.

I'm using C# and ASP.net MVC. Could you please guide?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have link your user managed identity to the app service (see steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/howto-integrate-azure-managed-service-identity?tabs=core2x)), you can use it from C# using the `Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication`. You will find examples [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/service-to-service-authentication) (when doing the `GetAccessTokenAsync` you will need to pass the graph's resource id).

If you want to make a call to access a user information, you will most likely run into permissions issues (the managed identity might not have permissions to access user's info). If it's the case, you should use an application instead of a managed identity to be able to use the [On-Behalf Of flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow).

Comment: Abinash Tumulu, was it helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Not C#, but for those who are interested in accessing the Microsoft Graph API with managed identities via the `@azure/identity` Node SDK

```js
import { DefaultAzureCredential } from '@azure/identity';
const authToken = await credential.getToken(['https://graph.microsoft.com/']);
const response = await fetch('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me', {
            headers: { Authorization: authToken.token }
        });
console.log(await response.text());
```